# batch script: Edit date and hour on windows xp

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I would like to automatically change the time and date in windows xp with a batch script, recovering hour from the internet.

Is this possible?

I ask this because you will be discharged the battery and the bios each time of course I do not have the correct time.

Unfortunately for now I can not replace it, so I devrei adapt with something!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's pretty simple:

```
w32tm /resync
```